# Xamarin iOS save on realm db when app is closed

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, realm, apple-push-notifications

I would like to save a notification on realm db when push notification is received while app is closed, it works when is running in foreground or background, but when it is closed not works and I cant catch any exception.

```
public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
    {
        if (null != userInfo && userInfo.ContainsKey(new NSString("aps")))
        {
            NSDictionary aps = userInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;

            string title = "Agendarum Informa";
            string notificationMessage = string.Empty;

            if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("title")))
                title = (aps[new NSString("title")] as NSString).ToString();
            if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("alert")))
                notificationMessage = (aps[new NSString("alert")] as NSString).ToString();

            UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView()
            {
                Title = title,
                Message = notificationMessage
            };

            try
            {
                var now = DateTime.Now;

                Realm _realm;
                _realm = Realm.GetInstance();
                _realm.Write(() =>
                {
                    _realm.Add(new Models.RealmObjects.Notification()
                    {
                       Title = alert.Title,
                       Message = notificationMessage,
                       Date = now
                    });
                });

            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                UIAlertView alertEx = new UIAlertView()
                {
                    Title = "ERRO",
                    Message = ex.Message
                };

                alertEx.AddButton("OK");
                alertEx.Show();
            }

            alert.AddButton("OK");
            alert.Show();
        }

    }
```

**NOTE: On Android it works fine...**

Any ideias?
Thanks.

Comment: Read the "Discussion" section at:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application?language=objc

Comment: Thanks! I changed ReceivedRemoteNotification to DidReceiveRemoteNotification then checked Background fetch in info.plist and it works fine!